# Compare two JSON objects in Angular

Tags: json, angular

I want to check if two JSON objects are same in Typescript(Angular), ignoring some key value pairs which may be optional.

```
obj1 = {name: 'Anna', password: 'test123', status: 'active'}
obj2 = {name: 'Anna', password: 'test123'}
```

Technically 'status' is optional, so I want the comparison to return true only considering first two properties. How to check this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could:

- Get common keys of obj1 and obj2 (with a set)
- Compare each key one-to-one

```
function compare(obj1, obj2) {
  const commonKeys = [...new Set([...Object.keys(obj1), ...Object.keys(obj2)])];

  for (const key of commonKeys) {
    if (obj1[key] !== obj2[key]) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 Boolean theSame= obj1.name==obj2.name && obj1.password==obj2.password;
```